# How can I determine if a Camunda webapp is running in EE version

Tags: javascript, web-applications, camunda

I'd like to had a column to a table of a, normally, community version feature.
But the content of this column (something related to the process instance history) is only available in the EE version.
Is there a way to find out when (or not) if the webapps are running on a EE server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the CE and EE version of the webapps is the availability of some plugins. The history plugin is EE only, but you can find out if it is available via the ViewsProvider:

```
var processInstancePlugins = Views.getProviders({ component: 'cockpit.processInstance.view' });

var hasHistoryPlugin = processInstancePlugins.filter(function(plugin) {
  return plugin.id === 'history';
}).length > 0;
```

If `hasHistoryPlugin` is then true, you can perform some Javascript to display the Enterprise only features.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed a neat solution which consist in getting the `Views` provider (as Angular DI thingy) and then check if the relevant (EE only) plugin is available.
This solution is used here:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-webapp/blob/48cfc96fcd9f97a9fde741987891ba9901e33bd3/webapp/src/main/resources-plugin/decisionList/app/views/decisionDefinition/decisionInstanceTable.js#L19